# Referencia de função no Array em Ruby

Tags: array, ruby

Eu não consegui entender como é a relação em Ruby da referencia de uma variável array (**best** e **vector**) com o retorno de uma função (**fitness** ou **bitstring** por exemplo).

Considere o caso seguinte:

```
best[:fitness]
```

Onde **best** é um array e **fitness** é uma função, o que será solicitado na variável array ? e o que será referenciado pela função ?

Vejam o código completo:

```
def objective_function(vector)
    return vector.inject(0.0) {|sum, x| sum + (x ** 2.0)}
end

def random_bitstring(num_bits)
    return (0...num_bits).inject(""){|s,i| s<<((rand<0.5) ? "1" : "0")}
end

def decode(bitstring, search_space, bits_per_param)
    vector = []
    search_space.each_with_index do |bounds, i|
        off, sum = i*bits_per_param, 0.0
        param = bitstring[off...(off+bits_per_param)].reverse
        param.size.times do |j|
            sum += ((param[j].chr=='1') ? 1.0 : 0.0) * (2.0 ** j.to_f)
        end
        min, max = bounds
        vector << min + ((max-min)/((2.0**bits_per_param.to_f)-1.0)) * sum
    end
    return vector
end

def fitness(candidate, search_space, param_bits)
    candidate[:vector]=decode(candidate[:bitstring], search_space, param_bits)
    candidate[:fitness] = objective_function(candidate[:vector])
end

def binary_tournament(pop)
    i, j = rand(pop.size), rand(pop.size)
    j = rand(pop.size) while j==i
    return (pop[i][:fitness] < pop[j][:fitness]) ? pop[i] : pop[j]
end

def point_mutation(bitstring, rate=1.0/bitstring.size)
    child = ""
    bitstring.size.times do |i|
        bit = bitstring[i].chr
        child << ((rand()<rate) ? ((bit=='1') ? "0" : "1") : bit)
    end
    return child
end

def crossover(parent1, parent2, rate)
    return ""+parent1 if rand()>=rate
    child = ""
    parent1.size.times do |i|
        child << ((rand()<0.5) ? parent1[i].chr : parent2[i].chr)
    end
    return child
end

def reproduce(selected, pop_size, p_cross, p_mut)
    children = []
    selected.each_with_index do |p1, i|
        p2 = (i.modulo(2)==0) ? selected[i+1] : selected[i-1]
        p2 = selected[0] if i == selected.size-1
        child = {}
        child[:bitstring] = crossover(p1[:bitstring], p2[:bitstring], p_cross)
        child[:bitstring] = point_mutation(child[:bitstring], p_mut)
        children << child
        break if children.size >= pop_size
    end
    return children
end

def bitclimber(child, search_space, p_mut, max_local_gens, bits_per_param)
    current = child
    max_local_gens.times do
        candidate = {}
        candidate[:bitstring] = point_mutation(current[:bitstring], p_mut)
        fitness(candidate, search_space, bits_per_param)
        current = candidate if candidate[:fitness] <= current[:fitness]
    end
    return current
end

def search(max_gens, search_space, pop_size, p_cross, p_mut, max_local_gens, p_local, bits_per_param=16)
    pop = Array.new(pop_size) do |i| {:bitstring=>random_bitstring(search_space.size*bits_per_param)}
    end
    pop.each{|candidate| fitness(candidate, search_space, bits_per_param) }
    gen, best = 0, pop.sort{|x,y| x[:fitness] <=> y[:fitness]}.first
    max_gens.times do |gen|
        selected = Array.new(pop_size){|i| binary_tournament(pop)}
        children = reproduce(selected, pop_size, p_cross, p_mut)
        children.each{|cand| fitness(cand, search_space, bits_per_param)}
        pop = []
        children.each do |child|
            if rand() < p_local
                child = bitclimber(child, search_space, p_mut, max_local_gens, bits_per_param)
            end
            pop << child
        end
        pop.sort!{|x,y| x[:fitness] <=> y[:fitness]}
        best = pop.first if pop.first[:fitness] <= best[:fitness]
        puts ">gen=#{gen}, f=#{best[:fitness]}, b=#{best[:bitstring]}"
    end
    return best
end

if __FILE__ == $0
    # problem configuration
    problem_size = 3
    search_space = Array.new(problem_size) {|i| [-5, +5]}
    # algorithm configuration
    max_gens = 100
    pop_size = 100
    p_cross = 0.98
    p_mut = 1.0/(problem_size*16).to_f
    max_local_gens = 20
    p_local = 0.5
    # execute the algorithm
    best = search(max_gens, search_space, pop_size, p_cross, p_mut, max_local_gens, p_local)
    puts "done! Solution: f=#{best[:fitness]}, b=#{best[:bitstring]}, v=#{best[:vector].inspect}"
end
```

**obs:** Esse código é uma implementação de um Algoritmo Memetico, que por sua vez é uma variação de um Algoritmo Evolucionário. 
Um Algoritmo Memetico tecnicamente busca a melhor solução pra um problema em um conjunto de soluções, a partir de uma busca global dos resultados integrada a uma otimização a cada ciclo/geração que seleciona variações de uma boa solução a partir de uma busca local dos resultados.

Meu objetivo é traduzir o código para programação Matlab.

Comment: `best` é um `Hash` (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html) e `best[:fitness]` retorna o valor associado a chave `:fitness` do hash `best`.

Answer (score 0):

@guiGS falou é isso, best é um Hash e :fitness é simplesmente a chave de acesso de uma posição desse hash.
Executei seu código e por exemplo o resultado final de best é

```
{:bitstring=>"011111111111111110000000000000000111111111111111", :vector=>[-7.629510948348184e-05, 7.629510948348184e-05, -7.629510948348184e-05], :fitness=>1.7462831193289442e-08}
```

Então quando eu acesso `best[:fitness]` isso vai resultar no valor `1.7462831193289442e-08` que é o valor correspondente da chave `:fitness`

Creio que em MatLab a estrutura correspondente é o `containers.Map` (disponível na versão 7.7 (R2008b) ) data structure. veja [MATLAB Map containers](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html) para mais. Ela remove algumas restrições que o STRUCT tem, por exemplo:

```
c = containers.Map
c('fitness') = 1.7462831193289442e-08
keys(c)
values(c)
```